# check if product attribute exists in upgradeData.php

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, upgrade, custom-attributes

I have a custom product attribute named **`additional_cost`**. Now I want to delete this **`additional_cost`** attribute or I want to update it. In order to do this both I need to first check if this attribute already exist.

I want to check the attribute in **`UpgradeData.php`** script. So how can I solve this problem

```
    $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

    $eavSetup->removeAttribute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
        'additional_cost'
    );
```

The removing code is ready. What will be the if statement?

Comment: please show your some code of upgradedata.php

Comment: Try using my answer if it works for you.

Comment: Resolved or still facing any issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this way:

```
if($eavSetup->getAttributeId(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, 'attr_code')) {
   //Create the attribute
 }
```

This will attempt to retrieve the attribute ID for the attribute with the code attr_code.

Comment: Thank you it works. I request you to change the if statement. if(!$setup->....) to if($setup->....)

Comment: Done. Glad that you made it done.